# Porting XPCOM Firefox extension to Chrome extension with NPAPI plugin

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi, xpcom

I have a extension, which uses *XPCOM* in *Firefox* to work. Now I would like to port that one to *Chrome*. Since the only way to use it is by using *npapi* and *npruntime*, I think I have to rewrite at least all the glue.

To keep as much of the sourcecode as possible, I was thinking of writing a `idl` converter similar to the `header.py` in *Mozilla*. Has this already been done and/or are there any resources for the switch from *XPCOM* to *NPAPI*?

Comment: XPCOM support for plugins has been [gone for a while](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/01/firefox-3-6-has-removed-support-for-xpcom-plugins/) - do you have an *extension*?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes, it is a "extension".

Comment: So you want to port an XPCOM-based extension to a Chrome extension, which might need an NPAPI plugin for native calls? Or what do you think you need NPAPI for?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche I do _know_, that I need native calls ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one "glue" generator that I know of for NPAPI, and that is [nixysa](http://code.google.com/p/nixysa/). If it were me, though, I'd just go ahead and port it to [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org); likely it wouldn't be any harder than porting it to straight npruntime and you'd then be able to take advantage of all the tweaks and fixes that an active community has found for different browsers, as well as potentially use it in other browsers.

I've been around in the plugin world for awhile, though, and I have never seen anything that converts a XPCOM .idl to one of the other formats; I don't think it'd be all that difficult to create such a thing, but I doubt many would need it at this point.

Hopefully something there helps.

Comment: I hugely dislike _FireBreath_, but I accept using it as it seems to be the only way to get _NPAPI_ working. _nixysa_ looks very promising, I will look into it. Should _nixysa_ not be sufficient I might be tempted to write my own 'typelib.py'.

Comment: @LCIDFire This is obviously not the place, but I would be quite interested to hear your frustrations with FireBreath as well as any suggestions for improvement; send a chat my way sometime if you're interested.

Comment: It's certainly not the case that it's "the only way to get NPAPI working". There are plenty of plugins written directly against NPAPI, so if you really dislike FireBreath more than NPAPI there's nothing stopping you from just using NPAPI directly. NPAPI is the plugin format the browser actually supports; FireBreath is just one abstraction layer that's been built on top of it.